# How to use passport to authenticate users and admins

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Im running a local strategy in passport and I have had an issue where it seems to authenticate users fine and I can have that user persisted across the site in a session, but not admins. I have the user and admin account under separate collections in MongoDB.I have tried plenty of different routes like having different passports for admin and user and having different databases for admin and users to no avail. I have come to a stand still. I would appreciate an advice!

```
//Passport.js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


// Loads in user model
const User = require('../models/userModel')
//Loads in the admin model
const Admin = require('../models/adminModel')


module.exports = function (authUser){
  authUser.use(
    'authUser',new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'username'}, (username, password, done)=>{
      //Match user
      const user = User.findOne({username: username})
      .then(user=>{
        if(!user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username'})
        }
        //Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
          if(err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user)
          }else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'})
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    })
  )

  authUser.serializeUser((user, done) =>{
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  authUser.deserializeUser((id, done) =>{
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  authUser.use(
    'admin',new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'username'}, (username, password, done)=>{
      //Match user
      const admin = Admin.findOne({username: username})
      .then(admin=>{
        if(!admin){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username'})
        }
        //Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, admin.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
          if(err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, admin)
          }else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'})
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    })
  )

  authUser.serializeUser((admin, done) =>{
    done(null, admin.id);
  });

  authUser.deserializeUser((id, done) =>{
    Admin.findById(id, (err, admin) => {
      done(err, admin);
    });
  });
}

//Authenticate.js
module.exports = {
  checkAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next()
    }
    // req.flash('error_msg', 'please login to view this resource')
    res.redirect('/Users/Login')
  },
  checkNotAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return res.redirect('/')
    }
    // req.flash('error_msg', 'please login to view this resource')
    return next()
  },
  checkAdminAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next()
    }
    // req.flash('error_msg', 'please login to view this resource')
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/Admin/SignIn')
  }
}

//Snippet from adminRoute.js
const passport = require('passport')
require('../config/passport.js')(passport)

app.get("/SignIn", checkNotAuthenticated,(req,res) =>{
  res.render("adminLogin.ejs")
})
app.get('/Orders', checkAdminAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Request.find({}).then(results => {
    res.render('orders.ejs', {
      Orders: results
    });
  })
})
// Login Handle
app.post('/SignIn', checkNotAuthenticated, (req,res, next)=>{
  passport.authenticate('admin',{
    successRedirect: '/AdminPage', //On success redirect to home
    failureRedirect: '/Admin/SignIn', //On failure redirect back to login page
    session: true,
    failureFlash: true
  })(req,res,next);
})
module.exports = app

//Snippet from userRoute.js
const passport = require('passport')
const authUser = new passport.Passport();
require('../config/passport.js')(authUser)
// DB config
const userDB = require('../config/keys').MongoURI
const User = require('../models/userModel')
app.get("/Login", checkNotAuthenticated,(req,res) =>{
  res.render("login.ejs")
})

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logOut()
  res.redirect('/Users/Login')
})

app.get('/Register', checkNotAuthenticated,  (req,res)=>{
  res.render("register.ejs")
})

// Login Handle
app.post('/Login', checkNotAuthenticated,(req,res, next)=>{
  authUser.authenticate('authUser',{
    successRedirect: '/', //On success redirect to home
    failureRedirect: '/Users/Login', //On failure redirect back to login page
    session: true,
    failureFlash:true
  })(req,res,next);
})
module.exports = app

// snippet from app.js
const passport = require('passport')
const authUser = new passport.Passport();
require('./config/passport.js')(authUser)
    app.use(authUser.initialize())
    app.use(authUser.session())
    app.use('/Users', require('./routes/userRoute'))
    app.use('/Admin', require('./routes/adminRoute'))
```

Comment: you don't need to use two localstrategies you could use only one for both user and admin

Comment: Hi Sven.hig, I appreciate the quick response. I am a bit confused though, how will passport know which collection to use in mongoDB?

Comment: Why not using only one model and one field like type = user or type = admin for the bifurcation? So you dont have to check 2 models, just one field on the same model

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it's working properly:

```
 //login route
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) =>{

 const email = req.body.email;
 const password = req.body.password;
 const userRole = 'user';

 //Some validations here ...

 const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
   if (user.role == 'admin') userRole = 'admin';

   // Other validations here ...

 
 
 if(userRole == 'admin'){
        passport.authenticate('local', {

            successRedirect: '/whereAuthenticatedAdminsAlowed',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash: true

        })(req, res, next);
    }
    else{
        passport.authenticate('local', {

            successRedirect: '/whereAuthenticatedUsersAlowed',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash: true

        })(req, res, next);
    }
}
```

and then in admin route (/admin) we need a middleware or a function to check if user is admin or not, and because we need to access to user.role, first we should make some changes in passport.serializeUser section:

```
  //In local strategy module after creating strategies:
  passport.serializeUser((user,done) =>{
      return done(null, {
           id: user.id,
           role: user.role
       });
  });

   //In admin route:
    router.get('/admin', (req,res) =>{
       const userRole = req.session.passport.user.role;
    
       if (isAuthenticated() && userRole == 'admin'){
           res.render('admin');
       }
       else{
            res.status(401);
            res.redirect(// access denied page or...);
       }

    });
```